# select columns from phenoData of ExpressionSet in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to select columns from phenoData of ExpressionSet in R. My data to be processes is teset.

```
class(teset)
[1] "ExpressionSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"

teset
ExpressionSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 19420 features, 253 samples 
 element names: exprs
   protocolData: none
phenoData
  sampleNames: TCGA-CV-7091-01A-11D-2012-08 TCGA-CJ-4875-01A-01D-1373-10 ...
    TCGA-25-1626-01A-01W-0615-10 (253 total)
  varLabels: time status ... Tumor_grade (7 total)
  varMetadata: labelDescription
featureData
  featureNames: 1060P11.3 A1BG ... ZZZ3 (19420 total)
  fvarLabels: EntrezID Symbol Desc Synonyms
  fvarMetadata: labelDescription
 experimentData: use 'experimentData(object)'
Annotation:
```

covariates information of teset:

```
names(pData(teset))
[1] "time"            "status"          "Age"             "Gender"         
[5] "TCGA_tumor_type" "Tumor_stage"     "Tumor_grade"
```

I only want a teset data without the first two columns in pData, namely all exprs data with pData(teset)[,-c(1,2)]. How can I do this?  Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I myself find a solution by creating a new one. I hope there might be better one:

te= ExpressionSet(assayData=exprs(teset),phenoData=phenoData(teset)[,-c(1,2)])